# How to get Next alarm time that i just set by AlarmManager set mehod

Tags: android

i am setting alarm like this

```
  AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

  alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,enter code here
        calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60 * 1000, pintent);
```

and i am using this for getting next alarm time but it gives me next alarm time of default        device alarmApp.

```
     android.provider.Settings.System.getString(
                getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED)
```

so what to do to get next alarm set by me ........

Comment: only for Your info: since API21 You can get the info with AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo getNextAlarmClock ();

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't read any information about the current alarms from the Alarm Manager, even if you set it yourself.

That means, you'll have to keep track of your alarm separately as a shared preference.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: this seems like a major oversight on behalf of Google

Answer (score 0):

After setting your alarm just put date/time of your alarm (in String format) into Settings.System. :

```
Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, "Your custom date/time of your alarm in String");
```

Remember to check if your new created alarm would be for sure the next alarm, because in Settings you can store only one String (it is replaced).